# Edit the width of an alert in bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to reduce the size of the alert. I've tried:

```
.alert{
    align-content: center;
    width: 20%;
}
```

But it doesn't work, I've also tried to reduce the whole container width. I've also tried to make the alert the width of his content but didn't work either:

```
.alert{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

My alerts contain  and many links like that:

```
<a href="website" id="links" target="_blank">/website1</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
.alert{
    align-content: center;
    width: 20% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked! can you explain me why it isn't working in my code?

Comment: I have used !important rule in my code.

The !important rule is a way to make your CSS cascade but also have the rules you feel are most crucial always be applied. A rule that has the !important property will always be applied no matter where that rule appears in the CSS document.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. 2 minutes until I can, thats why :)